# Image display issue after jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this page here: http://staging.morningsidepharm.com/news-blog/ which displays a list of blog posts in rows of 4.

I've applied the following animation using jQuery to the 'cards' so they fade in one by one:

```
jQuery('.fade-in-post-container .elementor-post').hide();
jQuery('.fade-in-post-container .elementor-post').each(function(i) {
    setTimeout(()=>{jQuery(this).show().addClass('animated fadeInUp')}, 250 * i);
});
```

This works fine, although when the cards fade in and have finished loading, some of the images develop a white border on the top and bottom.

**Like so:**

[image]

It seems to be different images each time, but this automatically fixes itself if I just shrink the size of the browser window, even by a tiny amount, the white strips disappear...

I'm really struggling with this and I'm not quite sure how to even find out what the issue is let alone fix it. I've tried to replicate this using JSfiddle, but that's proving difficult as there are so many styles and so much HTML in play.

If anyone could help it would be massively appreciated!

Thanks for looking.

Comment: You'll need to be able to demonstrate the issue with a **[mcve]** or there's no way to help you.  I know it's difficult to pull out only a small part of your site to reproduce the issue, but in doing so you'll quite often resolve the issue anyway.

Comment: Does it do the same if you remove the animation?

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and say the `<img>`s being set to `width: calc(100% + 1px);` is what causes that, rounding errors basically.

Comment: Archer - thanks, I did try and replicate the setup but failed, however this post and people's ideas were really helpful and gave me an idea of what part to look at - It didn't happen when I removed the animation, but someone below mentioned the image needing to be set to 100% and cover - So I've added that and it seems to have fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="elementor-post__thumbnail__link" href="">
    <div class="elementor-post__thumbnail">
        <img src="">
    </div>
</a>
```

That's the state of your thumbnail element after loading. You're missing `elementor-fit-height` class for `elementor-post__thumbnail` div and it has `height: 100%` property for `img`. You need to fix your javascript for adding this class.

Comment: Thanks Sharak, I've applied the CSS height:100%; to the image and hat seems to have worked!

Comment: @ShaunTaylor I suggest you work on that javascript though because with fixed 100% height you'll soon run into similar problem when you add portrait image. It's going to fit the height, but you'll have borders on the sides. I assume this script is there exactly for that. So just make it work on page load and you'll be good.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not 100% sure what you mean? I understand the issue of adding a portrait pic... But I thought the script did actually run on page load?

Answer (score 1):

You have to just add this 2 lines css in img tag but you must have to use parent class when add css for the image.

```
<style>
img{
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
</style>
 <a class="elementor-post__thumbnail__link" href="">
    <div class="elementor-post__thumbnail">
        <img src="">
    </div>
 </a>
```

I hope so this things works.

Comment: Thanks, Hardik Karangia! I did add the suggested CSS to .elementor-post__thumbnail img {} - and it seemed to work, however, I'm giving the answer to the guy below as he got there first. Thanks for your help :)